# Android studio 2.1 Unable to find toolchain of ndk-bundle

Tags: android-ndk, android-studio-2.1

After upgrade to Andriod studio 2.1, 
I run into an eror:

```
**Error:Unable to find toolchain: <workingRoot>/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt**
```

and I check the directory ***/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/.*** and there is nothing inside.

I can build the project successfully before the Android studio is upgraded.
Do anyone know how to rip off this error and share me your cure? Thanks

Comment: @rmtheis <--thanks. Let me try to google some **clang** related posts.

Comment: After all, I take a quick and dirty way: 
`
`1. create directory `
 `_<workingRoot>/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64_`

2. and go under above directory
 
    `git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/aarch64/aarch64-linux-android-4.9`

back to AS2.1, sync again.

Then the error message is gone.

Thanks!

Comment: @rmtheis, thanks to your remind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all, I take a quick and dirty way:

1. Create directory `<workingRoot>/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/pre‌​built/linux-x86_64`
2. Go under above directory and 
   `git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/aarch64/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/`
3. Back to AS2.1, sync again. Then the error message is gone.

Introduction address：

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/aarch64/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/

Comment: git repository not found

Comment: getting 404 page not found

Comment: you have to change repo in step 2 as per your error.