# Unable to find toolchain: Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Whenever I attempt to run a project in Android Studio, I get the message below:

Unable to find toolchain: /Users/christiantisby/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt

I'm not understanding what needs to be downloaded/added.  I have attempted to delete Android Studio and download it again, but I'm getting the same error. Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android studio 2.1 Unable to find toolchain of ndk-bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36976762/android-studio-2-1-unable-to-find-toolchain-of-ndk-bundle)

Comment: which gradle version you are using?

Comment: @Lucefer the accepted answer there is far more complicated than required.

Answer (score 0):

Update your gradle version and sync project.

In my case I updated it to `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1` and worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the SDK Manager in Android Studio and then download the `NDK` & `LLDB` (debugger); This would install it at `/Users/christiantisby/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle`.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the SDK Manager in Android Studio
[image]

After that delete NDK & LLDB

[image]

If this didn't help you then try Martin Zeitler answer.